# Patterns to Expressions

Tags: sequences-and-series

1) If you know that every 6th number from any given starting point is eliminated, how can you express this mathematically?
Example:

Starting on 8, eliminate 14, 20, 26, 32,...

Or if I want to change my starting point to $x$ and eliminate $x+6, x+12, x+18\dots$

2) (soft question) Is there a way to express the integers that were not eliminated?

Example:
After eliminating every $6(y)$ from a given starting point, the integers remaining also have a pattern- can this be expressed mathematically, or is there at least a better way to phrase that there is a pattern?

Comment: "every 6th number from any given starting point is eliminated" is already expressing it mathematically. If you have a different notion of "mathematically" in mind, you ought to specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S=\{x \in \mathbb{Z} | x>k\}$
Set $S$ contains all positive integers greater than $k$.

$M=\{k+6m | m > 1  \}$, where $k$ is your predefined number.
Some of the elements of this set are $k+6,k+12,k+18,\dots$

But our set of interest is $S\setminus M$.

Comment: This is gorgeous; exactly what I’m looking for!